# Request feature details in MapBox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to request a feature details (locality, place, region ...) from its id.

For example getting details for entries returned in context field by mapbox.places request.

An entry might be like 
  {id: "locality.6223273042152875", "Q270230", text: "8th arrondissement of Paris"}

So how to get geocode data for this locality using the id: locality.6223273042152875

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular forward geocode for the query "locality.6223273042152875" or reverse geocode its coordinates

Comment: indeed api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/locality.6223273042152875.json returns the geocoding data , thanks